# ggplotly ::\nplotly\nrenderPlotly` Error: number of columns of matrices must match

Tags: r, shiny, ggplotly

I am having trouble getting ggplotly to work within a shiny app, but I'm not sure shiny is the problem because I'm unable to create the ggplotly object from browser(). The behavior is that the app just hangs (shinycssloaders spinner) and produces a log trace (below).I tried placing a browser() just before the ggplotly call to look at the ggplot object and the ggmaply object. The ggplot object, Bmap, plots fine from the Browse[1] prompt. However, I get this error when trying to create the ggplotly object:

```
Browse[1]> Bmaply <- ggplotly(p=Bmap) Error in (function (...,
deparse.level = 1)  :    number of columns of matrices must match (see
arg 4)
```

Any help would be appreciated, and sorry that its not a reprex.  Not sure how to do that.

Code in server.R:

```
output$biomass.map <- plotly::renderPlotly({
 
     if (req(input$update==TRUE & 'map' %in% input$visual2)) {
        print('Creating biomass map')
        ids  <- c('fips.huc8')
        
        # get.along transposes and converts dt to Mg
        blong.sf <- mixed() %>%
         select(all_of(c(ids, 'supply.Mg'))) %>%
         get.along(ids=ids) 
        
        # map uses 'value' column
         Bmap <- map.fips.huc(blong.sf)
         browser()
         Bmaply <- ggplotly(p=Bmap)
         return(Bmaply)
     }
})
```

Code in ui.R (same problem if i remove the spinner):

```
        ## Display biomass map, data table, and supply curve
        ## withSpinner color needs to be hex
        tabPanel(h4("biomass"), id=2, value=2,
          fluidRow(
            column(plotlyOutput("biomass.map", width="100%") %>% withSpinner(color= "#00FFFF"), width=12, offset=0, div(style="padding: 0px 0px; margin:0%"), align='left'),
            column(DT::dataTableOutput("data.table"), width=12, offset=0, div(style="padding: 0px 0px; margin:0%"), align='left')
            #column(plotOutput("biomass.supply", width="100%"), width=12, offset=0, div(style="padding: 0px 0px; margin:0%"), align='left')
          )
        ),
```

Shiny log:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3849
[1] "Creating biomass map"
[1] "generating mixed-crop buffer data"
[1] "mixed: adding values"
Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 4)
  118: h
  117: .handleSimpleError
  116: <Anonymous>
  115: do.call
  114: cbind
  113: coord_4
  112: st_coordinates.sfc
  111: sf::st_coordinates
  110: fortify_sf
  109: structure
  108: prefix_class
  107: to_basic.GeomSf
  106: to_basic
  105: layers2traces
  104: gg2list
  103: ggplotly.ggplot
  102: ggplotly
  101: ::
plotly
renderPlotly [C:\Users\zij\Dropbox (ORNL)\MyProjects\Bioenergy\EcoServices-Valuation\ShinyVEST-v3-incentives/server.R#73]
  100: func
   99: promises::is.promising
   98: getFromNamespace("prepareWidget", "plotly")
   97: shinyRenderWidget
   96: func
   95: force
   94: withVisible
   93: withCallingHandlers
   92: domain$wrapSync
   91: promises::with_promise_domain
   90: captureStackTraces
   89: doTryCatch
   88: tryCatchOne
   87: tryCatchList
   86: tryCatch
   85: do
   84: hybrid_chain
   83: renderFunc
   82: output$biomass.map
   81: ..stacktraceon..
   80: orig
   79: func
   78: withCallingHandlers
   77: domain$wrapSync
   76: promises::with_promise_domain
   75: captureStackTraces
   74: withCallingHandlers
   73: shinyCallingHandlers
   72: force
   71: domain$wrapSync
   70: promises::with_promise_domain
   69: private$withCurrentOutput
   68: force
   67: withVisible
   66: withCallingHandlers
   65: domain$wrapSync
   64: promises::with_promise_domain
   63: captureStackTraces
   62: doTryCatch
   61: tryCatchOne
   60: tryCatchList
   59: tryCatch
   58: do
   57: hybrid_chain
   56: force
   55: withVisible
   54: withCallingHandlers
   53: domain$wrapSync
   52: promises::with_promise_domain
   51: captureStackTraces
   50: doTryCatch
   49: tryCatchOne
   48: tryCatchList
   47: tryCatch
   46: do
   45: hybrid_chain
   44: observe
   43: <observer:output$biomass.map>
   42: contextFunc
   41: env$runWith
   40: force
   39: domain$wrapSync
   38: promises::with_promise_domain
   37: withReactiveDomain
   36: domain$wrapSync
   35: promises::with_promise_domain
   34: ctx$run
   33: run
   32: withCallingHandlers
   31: domain$wrapSync
   30: promises::with_promise_domain
   29: captureStackTraces
   28: withCallingHandlers
   27: shinyCallingHandlers
   26: force
   25: withVisible
   24: withCallingHandlers
   23: domain$wrapSync
   22: promises::with_promise_domain
   21: captureStackTraces
   20: doTryCatch
   19: tryCatchOne
   18: tryCatchList
   17: tryCatch
   16: do
   15: hybrid_chain
   14: flushCallback
   13: FUN
   12: lapply
   11: ctx$executeFlushCallbacks
   10: .getReactiveEnvironment()$flush
    9: flushReact
    8: serviceApp
    7: ..stacktracefloor..
    6: withCallingHandlers
    5: domain$wrapSync
    4: promises::with_promise_domain
    3: captureStackTraces
    2: ..stacktraceoff..
    1: runApp
```

Comment: The whole if clause seems doubious to me. You should check if it actually works as you expect, by plotting something that will work for sure.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this.  Actually, this works when I substitute straight ggplot2 without ggplotly. That version is deployed here: https://www.shinyapps.io/admin/#/application/9160557. The if construct is used (in other function blocks also) to prevent re-executing except when the update button is clicked and the user wants to see a map.